# Interior and closure of an arbitrary product

Tags: general-topology

Let $J$ be a non-empty subset of the set $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,...\}$ of natural numbers and consider $X = \mathbb{R}^J$ with the product topology.

$(1)$ Show that the following statement holds:

$\operatorname{int}(A) = \prod \operatorname{int}(A_\alpha)$ for every subset $A = \prod A_\alpha$ of $X$ if and only if $J$ is finite.

$(2)$ Decide, for which non-empty subsets $J$ of $\mathbb{N}$ each of the following assertions is true:

$\operatorname{cl}(A) = \prod \operatorname{cl}(A_\alpha)$ for every subset $A = \prod A_\alpha$ of $X$.

I'm not sure where to start with either of these problems...
I know that a basis for R consists of all open intervals in R, so a basis for R^J consists of all the products of the form (a1,b1) x .... x (an,bn).

Let U be any non-empty open subset of R, which contains some open subset from the standard base of the product...

Comment: What is RJ? is R just some scalar? and what is A?

Comment: @ellya I'm almost sure that should be $X = \mathbb{R}^J$.

Comment: oh.. yes that makes things clearer

Comment: And $A\alpha$? $A_\alpha$, $A\cdot \alpha$, $A^\alpha$??

Comment: I think it is $A_\alpha$ where $A=\prod_\alpha A_\alpha$

Comment: Ellya and Daniel are correct in their assumptions. I don't have a math program to fix these.

Comment: What's the usual basis of open sets for the product topology? Just writing that down should give you an idea about the first part.

Comment: all products of open intervals....

Answer (score 1):

Note that the basis elements of the product topology are of the form $\prod U_{i}$ where each $U_{i}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $U_{i}=\mathbb{R}$ for all but **finitely** many $i$.

Lets take a look at the first question together, it should give you a good idea of how to approach the second part as well.

Note that in the statement int$(A)=\prod\mathrm{int}(A_{\alpha})$ you have that an open set of the product topology must equal a product of open sets. If $J$ would be infinite, can you find a set $A$ for which the right hand part of the equality yields a set that is not open? (Think about a collection of open sets whose infinite product is not open). This gives you the direction $\Rightarrow$. For the reverse direction $\Leftarrow$, note that $$\prod\mathrm{int}(A_{\alpha})\subseteq \prod A_{\alpha}=A$$ and use finiteness of $J$ and the characterisation of interior which says that int$(A)$ is the largest open set contained in $A$ to conclude int$(A)\supseteq\prod\mathrm{int}(A_{\alpha})$. For the reverse inclusion, note that for any basis element of the product topology $U=\prod U_{\alpha}$ with $$\prod U_{\alpha}\subseteq \mathrm{int}(A)=\mathrm{int}\Big(\prod A_{\alpha}\Big)\subseteq \prod A_{\alpha}$$
you have $U_{\alpha}\subseteq A_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha$. Use the same characterisation of int$(A_{\alpha})$ as we did before to conclude that $U_{\alpha}\subseteq\mathrm{int}(A_{\alpha})$ for all $\alpha$. So $U\subseteq \prod \mathrm{int}(A_{\alpha})$. Since int$(A)$ is an open set then it is a union of the basis elements, each which is a subset of $\prod\mathrm{int}(A_{\alpha})$, which implies that int$(A)\subseteq \prod\mathrm{int}(A_{\alpha})$.

To attack part $(2)$ you can use the analogous characterisation of closure, which states that cl$(A)$ is the smallest closed set that contains $A$. I can answer some of your questions in the comments section if you run in to obstacles.

Comment: @t-eskin, I'm proving second part of closure inequality: $\prod{\operatorname{cl}(A_\alpha)} \subseteq \operatorname{cl}(\prod{A_\alpha})$. I can show that for any closed set $C = \prod{C_\alpha}$, if $\operatorname{cl}(\prod{A_\alpha}) \subseteq C$ then $\prod{\operatorname{cl}(A_\alpha)} \subseteq C$. But does this imply that $\prod{\operatorname{cl}(A_\alpha)} \subseteq \operatorname{cl}(\prod{A_\alpha})$? I'm trying to convince myself that it is true, but there is an assumption that $C$ is a product/box and what if $\operatorname{cl}(A)$ is not a product/box and has some "wired" points?